# Get H1 from another page

Tags: jquery

I would like to make a contents page on the fly,

Can i target a h1 tag on say page 001.html & 002.html and display it on contents.html using jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
$('#result').load('001.html h1');
```

Where the `h1` is a selector that will select your heading.

Comment: that's assuming the `<h1>` is id'd as `header`. (Judging by original question, we can't assume this).

Comment: And that that is what Ma9ic asked :)

Comment: @Brad Christie Ok, I've edited my answer. I just copied a snippet from the docs, but on further reading it seems you can use any selector. Now we're assuming he only has one `h1` though :)

Answer (score 2):

contents.html

```
<div id="target"></div>

<script src=//jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.get('001.html', function(html){
    $('#target').text($('h1',html).text());
  });
</script>
```

Where `#target` is an element with the id `target` within the contents page, and `h1` is a selector that locates the `<h1>` you're after on the 001.html page.